# Reg: Web page images are not loading properly when accessing through Jmeter HTTP test script recorder

Tags: jmeter

When i try to access the webpage via Jmeter Http test script recorder after configuring the proxy settings, it is not loading the webpage UI properly but requests are captured perfectly in jmeter.

I tried the following things:
I have added the Apache Root CA certificate
and Set the correct Time Zones

**Note: Issue occurs for particular website only.** Other websites are loading properly.

Please help on this to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is due to SSL algorithm mismatch between java version of JMeter and target website.

You may have to enable/disable some algorithm in java.security file.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Can u please assist me where to find that java.security file and what changes needs to be done in detail.

Comment: See this https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that they are 3rd-party images, i.e. residing on different domains other than your application. If this is the case and you still want to record them - consider using HTTPS Domains input of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

[image: JMeter HTTPS(S) Test Script Recorder Domains]

As per documentation:

> List of domain (or host) names for HTTPS. Use this to pre-generate certificates for all servers you wish to record.

However if the domains are "alien" and not controllable by you - it is even good that JMeter cannot capture the images as in any case you should exclude external resources from your load test as you should focus solely on your application and discard any 3rd-party resources (images, scripts, styles, etc) so if your application includes JavaScript library like [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) from its own repository - you need to include it, however if it is being fetched from the outside world - it should be excluded.

---

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), in this way you will not have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates and your site layout will not be broken due to missing [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) proxy in between the browser and the application under test.